# Login using Facebook Authentication - FBApp Installed

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am following the Scrumptious sample that is on the FB Developers site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/) I successfully implemented everything up to the end of step 2 without any errors.
But i noticed that if i have the Android FB Application installed on my device then it does not log in.

It asks permission to access my public profile and friend list (to which i reply OK). After that it execute onSessionStateChange() but state = CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED.

I did verify that:

1. My app is listed on https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. I checked and my Native Android App option is ticked
3. i also have my Package Name, Hash Key entered.
4. The Facebook Login option is also enabled.

Please can someone help me to get this working :-( i am
struggling with this for 2 days already and no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Problem has been resolved. After i generated the HashKey using the KeyTool.exe and entered the password as android it gave me a different key. I copied this to the dashBoard on Facebook and it worked. Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved. After i generated the HashKey using the KeyTool.exe and entered the password as android it gave me a different key. I copied this to the dashBoard on Facebook and it worked. Sorry for wasting your time